# How to confirm ok of popup in Behat?

Tags: php, popup, automated-tests, behat, mink

I want to confirm the popup when it appears.
Here is the feature file:

```
And I wait 10 seconds
Then I confirm the popup
```

And The FeatureContext file:

```
<?php

    use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
    use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
    use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
    use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;
    use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
    use Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver;

    class FeatureContext extends MinkContext { 
    /**
     * @when /^(?:|I )confirm the popup$/
     */
        public function confirmPopup()   {
            $this->getSession()->getDriver()->getWebDriverSession()->accept_alert();
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work. It shows the following error:
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdqVr.png)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using Behat 3, you can add this step in any context that extends `Page` object.

```
public function iConfirmThePopup()
{
    $this->getDriver()->getWebDriverSession()->accept_alert();
}
```

If you have any delay in the pop-up appearing you can add a `sleep(1);` in the method before calling the accept alert method.

> This code would work for alert type, if the pop-p is not an alert then you need to use a regular click on the ok/confirm button.

Answer (score -2):

You can use:

```
/**
 * @when /^(?:|I )confirm the popup$/
 */
public function confirmPopup()
{
    $this->getSession()->getDriver()->getWebDriverSession()->accept_alert();
}
```

I found this file, very handy:

https://gist.github.com/blazarecki/2888851

This file contain how to handle them all popups

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)